# Field guids shown in Edit Frame instead of edit button

Tags: experience-editor

We can see a list of field guids on Edit Frame on other environments to local dev like this:

[image]

All is working fine locally:

[image]

Image is not available in iconcache:

[image]

Looks like the problem is only with Azure PaaS.

Has somebody solved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like on Azure PaaS, icons are not accessible / visible via `/temp/iconcache/` path. You need to use `/~/icon/` instead in your path to get icons. This works both locally and also on server to get icons.